# Extending the Delta-Wye/∆-Y Transformation to higher polygons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

I was looking at the derivation of the ∆-Y Transformation and decided to replicate the process with a square and its diagonals, i.e. I tried to create a Square-Cross/□-X transformation. But the equations so formed do not seem to have a solution. There are 4 variables and 6 equations, and to check whether they have a solution I used the Rouché-Capelli theorem. The rank of the coefficient matrix is 4 while the rank of the augmented matrix is 5, which implies that no solutions exist. Am I doing something wrong or is extending the Delta-Wye transformation to higher polygons just not possible? If it's the latter, why not?

[image: My Attempt]

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-mesh_transform

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks!